# ArrayList and inheritance with Polymorphism and Copy Constructors

Tags: java, polymorphism

I have a Parent object, a `BankAccount` that is an `Arraylist`, and three subclass that inherent from `BankAccount`:

- Checkings
- Savings
- CD account

When I try to access the methods of the child after making a polymorphic call I get that the BankAccount object of, lets say, CDAccount type does not have access to those methods.

See code:

```
} else if(bank.getAcct(index).accType.equalsIgnoreCase("Savings")) 
{
    BankAccount bankAcc = new SavingsAccount ((SavingsAccount) bank.getAcct(index));
    bankAcc.makeWithdrawal(requestedAccount, amountToWithdraw);                                 
} else {
    BankAccount bankAcc = new CheckingAccount ((CheckingAccount) bank.getAcct(index));
```

I try to cast here but get an error saying how the args I'm sending to `makeWithdrawl()` (which was overwritten by `CheckingAccount`) cannot take a `BankAccount` object

```
bankAcc.makeWithdrawal( amountToWithdraw );
```

See attempted casting in this code snippet:

```
if( bank.getAcct(index).accType.equalsIgnoreCase("CD")) {
    BankAccount bankAcc = new CDAccount
            (bank.getAcct(bank.getAcct(index).getAccDet()).getSocSec()))
    //
    bankAcc.makeWithdrawal( amountToWithdraw);
```

And this:

```
public BankAccount getAcct(String social)
{
    int index = findAcctSSN(social);
    // Uses Copy Cons new BankAccount
    return new (BankAccount) CheckingAccount(bankAccList.get(index));
}
```

Comment: Why would `makeWithdrawal` need an account parameter? Aren't you withdrawing from the account you call the method on?

Comment: Why are you copying the account object before making a withdrawal? Now you have 2 account objects, with different balances, but don't they still represent the same real account?

Comment: I'm supposed to send a copy. The methods return copies and all the classes have copy constructors.

Comment: show us some more code

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to know how best to help here, because there is missing code and context:

1. You say that a `BankAccount` object is an `ArrayList`, but clearly is not, due to a `makeWithdrawal()` method, but no other use of `ArrayList` is visible - possibly `bankAccList` ?
2. There appear to be two `makeWithdrawal()` methods, one with 1 arg, one with 2 args.
3. Does `getAcct()` method take `String social` or `int index`, or are there two overloaded methods? This is further confused by the chained `bank.getAcct(bank.getAcct(index).getAccDet()).getSocSec())` clause.
4. The idiom `return new (BankAccount) CheckingAccount()` is incorrect syntax. Either `CheckingAccount` extends `BankAccount` or it doesn't. If it does, then casting is not necessary. If it doesn't, casting will fail.

Assuming

```
public class CheckingAccount extends BankAccount {
}
```

Then this will work:

```
public BankAccount getAcct(...)
{
    return new CheckingAccount(...);
}
```

And is equivalent to:

```
public BankAccount getAcct(...)
{
    return (BankAccount) new CheckingAccount(...); // Cast before the "new"
}
```